# Having trouble making object move without flickering in Java

Tags: java, graphics, paint

I have looked into Double Buffering and plan on implementing it eventually but as of right now I can't figure out how to use it or anything like it. I am trying to make pong so I plan on adding three objects total but for now I just want to get one object to work smoothly. I'm fairly new to graphics so I don't know entirely what I'm doing and I'm just trying to learn as I go.

Here is my code:

Pong:

```
public static void main(String[]args) {
    JFrame window= new JFrame();
    window.setTitle("Pong Game");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,500));
    window.pack();
    window.setVisible(true);
    Ball ball= new Ball();
    Paddle player= new Paddle();
    window.getContentPane().add(ball);
    for(;;) {
        ball.move();
        //window.setContentPane(ball);
        window.setContentPane(player);
        player.move();
    }
}
```

Paddles:

```
double x, y, ymove;
boolean cpu;

public Paddle() {
    x=5;
    y=180;
    ymove=.1;
}

//passing an integer through to make the computer paddle
public Paddle(int a) {
    cpu= true;
    x=761;
    y=180;
    ymove=.1;
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.blue);
    g.fillRect((int)x, (int)y, 18, 120);
}

public void move() {
    y+=ymove;
    if(y>=500-160||y<=0) {
        ymove*=-1;
    }
}
```

Ball:

```
double x, y, xspeed, yspeed;

public Ball() {
    x=200;
    y=200;
    xspeed=0;
    yspeed=.1;
}

public void move() {
    x+=xspeed;
    y+=yspeed;
    if(y>=440||y<=0) {
        yspeed*=-1;
    }
}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillOval((int)x, (int)y, 20, 20);
}
```

Comment: Hi! Have you tried to pause the rapid reprint using something like _Thread.sleep_?

Comment: I've seen Thread but have no idea what it is so I haven't used it. For something like a timer, I tend to use System.currentTimeMillis. I'll definitely look into Thread though.

Comment: Alright. Put simply, [Thread.sleep](https://www.journaldev.com/1020/thread-sleep-java) lets the code "wait" for the specified time. This is not a direct fix, but limits the speed of the "page-flipping", i.e. the time between rendering. Try adding Thread.sleep(15) to the end of your loop. Is it still flickering?

Comment: That made it stop but it made me add throws InterruptedException to my main and the ball is a little blurry. It did make it a lot smoother overall so thank you.

Comment: The Exception is required because the waiting thread may be "interrupted". Non the less, i will add an answer for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Answer is a very very simplified explanation! I recommend checking out [this linux journal](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/169), which explores something similia.

The main issue, which causes the "flickering" is, that the draw is done "to fast".

Take your main loop:

```
for(;;) {
    ball.move();
    window.setContentPane(ball);
    window.setContentPane(player);
    player.move();
}
```

This loop updates the positions of the ball and afterwards "adds it to the content pane". While it is drawn, the next image is already added and drawn. This is causing the flickering (again, note: this is very simplified).

The simplest solution to fix the "flickering" is, to let the Thread sleep after it has drawn and "wait" until the draw is finished.

```
boolean running = true;
int delay = 15; // adjust the delay
while(running) {
    ball.move();
    player.move();
    window.setContentPane(ball);
    window.setContentPane(player);
    try {
        Thread.sleep(delay);
    } catch(InterruptedException e) {
        // We were interrupted while waiting
        // Something "woke us up". Stop the loop.
        e.printStackTrace();
        running = false;
    }
}
```

This Thread.sleep method let's the current [Thread](https://dzone.com/articles/java-thread-tutorial-creating-threads-and-multithr) "wait" for the specified time.

The delay can be adjusted to something more practical. You could for example calculate how many frames you want and sleep for that amount.

Another way would be to "time" the updates. This could be done with a timer. Since it is more or less deprecated, i implement it using the ScheduledExecutorService

```
int delay = 15; // adjust the delay

ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool();
scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        ball.move();
        player.move();
    }
}, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

As of Java8, you might write this using a Lambda like this:

```
scheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
    ball.move();
    player.move();
}, delay, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
```

To stop it, you could now call:

```
scheduledExecutorService.shutdown();
```

However: There are more sophisticated solutions. One is, as you already noted, the [double buffering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/fullscreen/doublebuf.html). But there are also multiple [different techniques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering), that compensate more difficult problems. They use something called page flipping.

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that you have split your paint methods,
if you make one class that is dedicated to doing the painting and you put all of your paints in one paint method it should work without flickering.

I would also recommend looking into making your paint calls run on a timer which lets you decide the refresh rate which usually leads to a smoother experience overall.

Here is an example of my graphics class in my latest game,

```
class GameGraphics extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private Timer refreshHZTimer;

private int refreshHZ = 10;
private int frameID = 0;

public GameGraphics(int width, int height) {

    setBounds(0,0, width, height);
    setVisible(true);

    refreshHZTimer = new Timer(refreshHZ, this);
    refreshHZTimer.start();

}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    frameID++;
    if (frameID % 100 == 1)
    System.out.println("Painting FrameID: " + frameID);
    repaint();

}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);

    //Init graphics
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    //Paint stuff here:
}
}
```

And add this code to your JFrame constructor:

```
    GameGraphics gpu = new GameGraphics(width, height);
    frame.add(gpu);
```

Comment: If you could add examples that would be much appreciated.

Comment: @JoshuaPaige added some examples